# gettablesize vs FD_SETSIZE, which to use?

Tags: sockets, archlinux

We just port some old software to a RH7 and valgrind send that the fd_set array was being written to beyond is array boundary.  Looking at the code the software is setting all the bits in the fd_set array.  The max value of the for loop is from gettablesize().  Depending on how the task is started the value returned is either 1024 or 4096.  When its 4096 the code is out of range.  Now clearly the code should be using FD_SETSIZE, but there is a question of why gettablesize() was ever being used for fd_set max value.   So what is the different between gettablesize() and FD_SETSIZE?  I assume that 1024 is the maximum number of socket file descriptors possible and gettablesize() is returning the maximum number of all types of file descriptors (sockets, files, etc).

1) should gettablesize() ever be used for socket connects like this?

2) why is gettablesize() returning different values depending on how the task is run?  ex. task is started via system() call with vagrind returns 4096, running on command line without or without valgrind 1024, etc.  What's going on?

Comment: getdtablesize (often) is a wrapper around getrlimit(), and it reports the size as imposed by the kernel. FD_SETSIZE is an implementation limit imposed by FD_SET, it could even be a constant, IIRC. Best option is probably to rewrite using poll().

Comment: Did you mean *get**d**tablesize*?

Comment: This a old code from the 90s that that was used in one of the subsystem.  As stated above, the was code wrong, but the question was why they decided to use gettablesize() in the first place.